# Starting KNIME from console: NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.knime.database.driver.DBDriverRegistry$DriverClassLoader

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, driver, knime

Because the operating system of my remote desktop computer that I am using for work prevents me from executing `EXE` files, I am now trying to find a workaround in order to use the software. These are the steps that I have taken so far:

1. I downloaded the [`KNIME Analytics Platform for Windows (zip archive)` from here](https://www.knime.com/download-install/windows/5/64bit) and unzipped it to `C:\Users\username\Downloads\knime_4.6.3`.
2. Then, I copied a `CMD` file, created by a colleauge, placed it in the very same folder and executed it in order to start the program. The contents of the file are as follows:

```
@echo off
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\OracleJDK\17-0-2
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\OracleJDK\17-0-2\bin;%PATH%

java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.100.v20201223-0822.jar -Djava.class.path=plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.100.v20201223-0822.jar -cp plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.100.v20210209-1541;plugins/org.knime.database_4.6.0.v202205251236/knime-db-core.jar -server -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -Dosgi.classloader.lock=classname -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=0 -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,javax/swing/text/GlyphView,getBreakSpot -Dknime.xml.disable_external_entities=true --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.channels=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx2048m -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=11001 -Dsun.awt.noerasebackground=true -Dequinox.statechange.timeout=30000 -Darrow.enable_unsafe_memory_access=true -Darrow.memory.debug.allocator=false -Darrow.enable_null_check_for_get=false --add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.spi=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED 

pause
```

3. After the program started, I went to `Help -> Install New Software... -> Manage...`. This opened a `Preferences` window with a tree structure set to the leaf `Install/Update -> Available Software Sites`.
4. I changed the URLs in the `Location` column form `https` to `http` in order to avoid having trouble with firewalls blocking traffic and clicked on `Apply and Close`.
5. Next, I went to `File -> Install KNIME Extensions...`.
6. There, I opened the node `KNIME & Extensions`, checked `KNIME JDBC Driver For Oracle Database` and clicked `Next >` twice.
7. After that, I selectd `I accept the terms of the license agreement` and clicked `Finish`.
8. When the `Software Updates` window opened, asking me the question `Restart KNIME Analytics Platform to apply the software update?`, I did *not* click on `Restart Now` but closed the program completely and executed the `CMD` file once again in order to start `KNIME`.
9. In order to create a new `KNIME` workflow, I went to the `KNIME Explorer` and right-clicked on `LOCAL (Local Workspace)` and then on `New KNIME Workflow...`.
10. I entered a name where it says `Name of the workflow to create:` and clicked `Finish`. This opened a new tab window in the middle of the screen with the name of my workflow.
11. In the `Node Repository`, I selected the node `DB -> Connection` and looked for the leaf `Oracle Connector`.
12. When I dragged and dropped this node onto my workspace, problems started to arise.

`KNIME` first prompted these messages to its console with a lot of `ERROR DBDriverRegistry` messages and two warnings:

```
WARN  Oracle Connector     3:1        Please install the KNIME JDBC Driver For Oracle Database plug-in or register your own driver. For more information on how to install the plug-in see https://docs.knime.com/latest/db_extension_guide/index.html#db_plugin.
WARN  Oracle Connector     3:1        Please register a compatible driver via the KNIME preference page. (For details see the log file)
```

The `log` file contains the following (`Das Handle ist ungültig.` = `The handle is invalid.`):

```
!SESSION 2022-11-14 09:59:42.581 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=17.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -Djava.class.path=plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.100.v20201223-0822.jar -cp plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.100.v20210209-1541;plugins/org.knime.database_4.6.0.v202205251236/knime-db-core.jar -server -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -Dosgi.classloader.lock=classname -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=0 -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,javax/swing/text/GlyphView,getBreakSpot -Dknime.xml.disable_external_entities=true --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.channels=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx2048m -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=11001 -Dsun.awt.noerasebackground=true -Dequinox.statechange.timeout=30000 -Darrow.enable_unsafe_memory_access=true -Darrow.memory.debug.allocator=false -Darrow.enable_null_check_for_get=false --add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.spi=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED
Command-line arguments:  -Djava.class.path=plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.100.v20201223-0822.jar -cp plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.100.v20210209-1541;plugins/org.knime.database_4.6.0.v202205251236/knime-db-core.jar -server -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -Dosgi.classloader.lock=classname -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=0 -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,javax/swing/text/GlyphView,getBreakSpot -Dknime.xml.disable_external_entities=true --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.channels=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx2048m -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=11001 -Dsun.awt.noerasebackground=true -Dequinox.statechange.timeout=30000 -Darrow.enable_unsafe_memory_access=true -Darrow.memory.debug.allocator=false -Darrow.enable_null_check_for_get=false --add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.spi=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2022-11-14 10:00:26.271
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2022-11-14 10:00:26.271
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for CTRL++:
Binding(CTRL++,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.gef.zoom_in,Zoom In,
        Zoom In,
        Category(org.eclipse.gef.category.view,View,View,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@3703a400,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,de,,system)
Binding(CTRL++,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.gef.zoom_in,Zoom In,
        Zoom In,
        Category(org.eclipse.gef.category.view,View,View,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@3703a400,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 4 0 2022-11-14 10:00:31.855
!MESSAGE WinHttp.GetProxyForUrl for pac failed with error 'Das Handle ist ungültig.
' #6.
```

And the Windows console showed these Java errors (output shortened (`...`)):

```
Nov. 14, 2022 10:00:21 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.CXFExtensionBundleListener addExtensions
INFORMATION: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs (166) [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSBindingFactory]
Nov. 14, 2022 10:00:21 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.CXFExtensionBundleListener addExtensions
INFORMATION: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http (170) [org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory, org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPWSDLExtensionLoader, org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.HTTPClientAssertionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.HTTPServerAssertionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.NoOpPolicyInterceptorProvider]
Nov. 14, 2022 10:00:21 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.CXFExtensionBundleListener addExtensions
INFORMATION: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http-hc (171) [org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduitFactory, org.apache.cxf.transport.ConduitInitiator]
Nov. 14, 2022 10:00:22 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFORMATION: Aries Blueprint packages not available. So namespaces will not be registered
Nov. 14, 2022 10:00:22 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFORMATION: Aries Blueprint packages not available. So namespaces will not be registered
ERROR    main WindowsDefenderExceptionHandler    PowerShell command powershell -inputformat none -outputformat text -NonInteractive -Command Get-MpComputerStatus -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AMServiceEnabled did not terminate successfully.
ERROR    main WindowsDefenderExceptionHandler    Stderr is:
ERROR    main WindowsDefenderExceptionHandler    Get-MpComputerStatus : Es ist ein allgemeiner Fehler aufgetreten, f?r den kein spezifischerer Fehlercode verf?gbar ist.
ERROR    main WindowsDefenderExceptionHandler    In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
ERROR    main WindowsDefenderExceptionHandler    + Get-MpComputerStatus -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object -ExpandPropert ...
ERROR    main WindowsDefenderExceptionHandler    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ERROR    main WindowsDefenderExceptionHandler        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_MpComputerStatus:ROOT\Microsoft\...pComputerStatus) [Get-MpComputerS
ERROR    main WindowsDefenderExceptionHandler       tatus], CimException
ERROR    main WindowsDefenderExceptionHandler        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x800106ba,Get-MpComputerStatus
ERROR    main WindowsDefenderExceptionHandler
Nov. 14, 2022 10:00:30 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer register
INFORMATION: Aries Blueprint packages not available. So namespaces will not be registered
ERROR    main DBDriverRegistry   Database driver wrapper creation failed for driver (H2) "H2".
ERROR    main DBDriverRegistry   Failed to load built-in database driver (H2) "H2" from extension org.knime.database.extensions.
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.knime.database.driver.DBDriverRegistry.createDriverWrapper(DBDriverRegistry.java:446)
        at org.knime.database.driver.DBDriverRegistry.lambda$3(DBDriverRegistry.java:558)
        at org.knime.database.util.ExtensionPoints.loadExecutableExtensions(ExtensionPoints.java:94)
        at org.knime.database.driver.DBDriverRegistry.loadExtensionDrivers(DBDriverRegistry.java:545)
        at org.knime.database.driver.DBDriverRegistry.<init>(DBDriverRegistry.java:599)
        at org.knime.database.driver.DBDriverRegistry.<clinit>(DBDriverRegistry.java:216)
        at org.knime.database.extension.oracle.node.connector.OracleDBConnectorSettings.<init>(OracleDBConnectorSettings.java:80)
        at org.knime.database.extension.oracle.node.connector.OracleDBConnectorNodeModel.<init>(OracleDBConnectorNodeModel.java:66)
        at org.knime.database.extension.oracle.node.connector.OracleDBConnectorNodeFactory.createNodeModel(OracleDBConnectorNodeFactory.java:61)
        at org.knime.database.extension.oracle.node.connector.OracleDBConnectorNodeFactory.createNodeModel(OracleDBConnectorNodeFactory.java:1)
        at org.knime.core.node.NodeFactory.callCreateNodeModel(NodeFactory.java:520)
        at org.knime.core.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:307)
        at org.knime.core.node.workflow.WorkflowManager.addNodeAndApplyContext(WorkflowManager.java:871)
        at org.knime.core.ui.wrapper.WorkflowManagerWrapper.createAndAddNode(WorkflowManagerWrapper.java:140)
        at org.knime.workbench.editor2.commands.CreateNodeCommand.lambda$0(CreateNodeCommand.java:183)
        at org.knime.workbench.ui.async.AsyncUtil.wfmAsyncSwitch(AsyncUtil.java:130)
        at org.knime.workbench.editor2.commands.CreateNodeCommand.execute(CreateNodeCommand.java:182)
        at org.eclipse.gef.commands.CommandStack.execute(CommandStack.java:228)
        at org.knime.workbench.editor2.WorkflowEditorDropTargetListener.handleDrop(WorkflowEditorDropTargetListener.java:511)
        at org.knime.workbench.editor2.NodeDropTargetListener.handleDrop(NodeDropTargetListener.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.gef.dnd.AbstractTransferDropTargetListener.drop(AbstractTransferDropTargetListener.java:183)
        at org.eclipse.jface.util.DelegatingDropAdapter$3.run(DelegatingDropAdapter.java:227)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
        at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
        at org.eclipse.jface.util.DelegatingDropAdapter.drop(DelegatingDropAdapter.java:224)
        at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DNDListener.handleEvent(DNDListener.java:94)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4209)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1043)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1067)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1052)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:766)
        at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget.Drop(DropTarget.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget.Drop_64(DropTarget.java:401)
        at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget$1.method6(DropTarget.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COMObject.callback6(COMObject.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COM.DoDragDrop(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DragSource.drag(DragSource.java:541)
        at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DragSource.lambda$0(DragSource.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4209)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1043)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4026)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3626)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
        at org.knime.product.rcp.KNIMEApplication.start(KNIMEApplication.java:183)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1461)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1434)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected java.lang.String java.lang.ClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @2c5157c9
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
        at org.knime.database.driver.DBDriverRegistry$DriverClassLoader.<clinit>(DBDriverRegistry.java:120)
        ... 66 more

...

ERROR    main DBDriverRegistry   Database driver wrapper creation failed for driver (built-in-oracle-19.14.0) "Driver for Oracle v. 19.14.0".
ERROR    main DBDriverRegistry   Failed to load built-in database driver (built-in-oracle-19.14.0) "Driver for Oracle v. 19.14.0" from extension org.knime.database.extensions.oracle.driver.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.knime.database.driver.DBDriverRegistry$DriverClassLoader
        at org.knime.database.driver.DBDriverRegistry.createDriverWrapper(DBDriverRegistry.java:446)
        at org.knime.database.driver.DBDriverRegistry.lambda$3(DBDriverRegistry.java:558)
        at org.knime.database.util.ExtensionPoints.loadExecutableExtensions(ExtensionPoints.java:94)
        at org.knime.database.driver.DBDriverRegistry.loadExtensionDrivers(DBDriverRegistry.java:545)
        at org.knime.database.driver.DBDriverRegistry.<init>(DBDriverRegistry.java:599)
        at org.knime.database.driver.DBDriverRegistry.<clinit>(DBDriverRegistry.java:216)
        at org.knime.database.extension.oracle.node.connector.OracleDBConnectorSettings.<init>(OracleDBConnectorSettings.java:80)
        at org.knime.database.extension.oracle.node.connector.OracleDBConnectorNodeModel.<init>(OracleDBConnectorNodeModel.java:66)
        at org.knime.database.extension.oracle.node.connector.OracleDBConnectorNodeFactory.createNodeModel(OracleDBConnectorNodeFactory.java:61)
        at org.knime.database.extension.oracle.node.connector.OracleDBConnectorNodeFactory.createNodeModel(OracleDBConnectorNodeFactory.java:1)
        at org.knime.core.node.NodeFactory.callCreateNodeModel(NodeFactory.java:520)
        at org.knime.core.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:307)
        at org.knime.core.node.workflow.WorkflowManager.addNodeAndApplyContext(WorkflowManager.java:871)
        at org.knime.core.ui.wrapper.WorkflowManagerWrapper.createAndAddNode(WorkflowManagerWrapper.java:140)
        at org.knime.workbench.editor2.commands.CreateNodeCommand.lambda$0(CreateNodeCommand.java:183)
        at org.knime.workbench.ui.async.AsyncUtil.wfmAsyncSwitch(AsyncUtil.java:130)
        at org.knime.workbench.editor2.commands.CreateNodeCommand.execute(CreateNodeCommand.java:182)
        at org.eclipse.gef.commands.CommandStack.execute(CommandStack.java:228)
        at org.knime.workbench.editor2.WorkflowEditorDropTargetListener.handleDrop(WorkflowEditorDropTargetListener.java:511)
        at org.knime.workbench.editor2.NodeDropTargetListener.handleDrop(NodeDropTargetListener.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.gef.dnd.AbstractTransferDropTargetListener.drop(AbstractTransferDropTargetListener.java:183)
        at org.eclipse.jface.util.DelegatingDropAdapter$3.run(DelegatingDropAdapter.java:227)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
        at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
        at org.eclipse.jface.util.DelegatingDropAdapter.drop(DelegatingDropAdapter.java:224)
        at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DNDListener.handleEvent(DNDListener.java:94)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4209)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1043)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1067)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1052)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:766)
        at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget.Drop(DropTarget.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget.Drop_64(DropTarget.java:401)
        at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget$1.method6(DropTarget.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COMObject.callback6(COMObject.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COM.DoDragDrop(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DragSource.drag(DragSource.java:541)
        at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DragSource.lambda$0(DragSource.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4209)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1043)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4026)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3626)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
        at org.knime.product.rcp.KNIMEApplication.start(KNIMEApplication.java:183)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1461)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1434)
WARN     main ServerDBConnectorSettings  Please install the KNIME JDBC Driver For Oracle Database plug-in or register your own driver. For more information on how to install the plug-in see https://docs.knime.com/latest/db_extension_guide/index.html#db_plugin.
WARN     main Node       Please register a compatible driver via the KNIME preference page. (For details see the log file)
```

Taking a look at `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.knime.database.driver.DBDriverRegistry$DriverClassLoader`, I cannot understand why this problem arises. There is a folder called `plugins\org.knime.database_4.6.0.v202205251236` which contains a `JAR` file named `knime-db-core.jar`. Inside this `JAR` file, there is a folder path `\org\knime\database\driver` which contains a subclass file `DBDriverRegistry$DriverClassLoader.class`.

**Why is it not found and initialised during execution?**

The `CMD` file was created according to the information that can be found in the `knime.ini` file. We suppose that something with the Java classpath is still not quite right in order to make the program work properly. Or can the solution be found somewhere else? Can this problem ever be solved or is it impossible to use `KNIME` in such a way? What can be done to make `KNIME` work under such circumstances?

Comment: The message 'Could not initialize class XYZ' does not mean that class XYZ could not be found. It means that the class was found, but something went wrong during static initialization when the JVM first tried to load it, so the JVM doesn't attempt to load the class again. The error that happened the first time could be anything: take a look back through the errors or logs to see if you can find any previous exceptions. In particular, look out for an `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

Comment: @LukeWoodward There is, indeed, such an error. [Here](https://pastebin.com/sXqpwB7j) are all the error messages.

Comment: I think the real problem here is the exception that caused the `ExceptionInInitializer` error.   (Please edit your question to include this exception, as it may be useful for other people who find your question in future, and the pastebin link might have broken by then.) However I am not sure why this happens. I note there already is a `--add-opens` 
command-line argument which I would have thought would stop you getting the error you are getting, but I am no expert in these matters, and have never used KNIME before, so I'm afraid I've gone about as far as I can.

Comment: @LukeWoodward The error is now included. Thank you and let’s hope that someone has an idea and can solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](https://forum.knime.com/t/starting-knime-from-console-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-org-knime-database-driver-dbdriverregistry-driverclassloader/54929/5?u=mgntmoe) in the `KNIME` forum helped to solve the problem.

My solution for `KNIME 4.6.3` is as follows:

```bash
@echo off
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\OracleJDK\17-0-2
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\OracleJDK\17-0-2\bin;%PATH%

java --add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.ssl=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.channels=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx2048m -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=11001 -Dsun.awt.noerasebackground=true -Dequinox.statechange.timeout=30000 -Darrow.enable_unsafe_memory_access=true -Darrow.memory.debug.allocator=false -Darrow.enable_null_check_for_get=false --add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.spi=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.100.v20201223-0822.jar -Djava.class.path=plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.100.v20201223-0822.jar -cp plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.100.v20210209-1541;plugins/org.knime.database_4.6.0.v202205251236/knime-db-core.jar -server -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -Dosgi.classloader.lock=classname -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=0 -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,javax/swing/text/GlyphView,getBreakSpot -Dknime.xml.disable_external_entities=true

pause
```

It does not work for the most recent version `KNIME 4.7.0` but with a few adaptions, we should be able to start and use this version as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer as alluded to by @LukeWoodward in the comments is that you need some additional `--add-opens` and `--add-exports` options on your command line.  You can find them in the `knime.ini` file in the installation folder, but they are as follows:

```
--add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.security.ssl=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.security.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.spi=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.nio.channels=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http=ALL-UNNAMED
```

I don't think you have all of those, trying to scroll across your command line.  It might be easier to specify the `knime.ini` as a properties file in the command although I'm not sure how to do that as there doesnt look to be consistent documentation.

The best and easiest solution of course would be to attempt to persuade your IT department to let you run the executable.

If none of that works, it may be worth trying the KNIME forum (https://forum.knime.com) or contacting their helpdesk

Comment: The first five lines of your code block were missing. I just added them but it still does not work. Asking a question in the `KNIME` forum can help to solve the problem maybe.

Comment: The question in the `KNIME` forum can be found [here](https://forum.knime.com/t/starting-knime-from-console-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-org-knime-database-driver-dbdriverregistry-driverclassloader/54929). Let’s hope for the best.